# How to manipulate history in React Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

**I am using:**

React, Redux, React-Router, Meteor

**Following situation:**

I have a modal with two tabs, based on the chosen tab a different list of selections will be shown in the content area, picking a selection will then give a list of subselection (all within the modal).

**Desired behavior:**

I want the user to be able to use the browser's back button to "undo" clicking on one of the tabs or picking a selection.

**What I tried so far with no success:**

1. use withRouter HOC to wrap my component, so that I would get access to history. I would then use history.push(currentUrl,{selectedTab:selection})
   -> Problem: the state from push wasn't stored on this histories location object, but only in the state of the history object associated with my rootcomponent (way further up the tree)
2. (More promising so far) Simply import the history I created with createHistory in another module and put that into component state on construction.
   I would then access the push method by using `this.state.history.push(currentUrl,{selectedTab:selection})`, which works fine and I can find the pushed state under `this.state.history.location.state.selectedTab`. However, using the browser's back button does not cause a rerender and therefore the selection will stay the same.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refined the second approach and it is working now. It does still feel hacky to import the history into my module (as a local variable), and thus bypassing react tree, redux store and react router altogether.
However, it is working and not causing any bugs so far. So here we go ...

I instantiate my history object in: 
 **store.js module**:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
...
const history = createHistory();
...
export { history , store }
```

that as you can see exports history. I then feed said history to my Router (ConnectedRouter in my case, as I am using react-router-redux) in: 
**routes.js module**

```
import { store , history } from '/imports/client/store';

const MyStoreRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={ history }>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing}/>
                        <Route path="/" component={MainApp}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

Now for the wacky part. I import the history into a display component and use it to set up a listener (to state changes in history.location) and change the state accordingly: 
**DisplayComponent.js module:**

```
import { history } from '/imports/client/store';
....
export default class EventCreationModal extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            selectedCategory: (history.location.state && history.location.state.category) ? history.location.state.category : 'sports',
        };
        history.listen((location,action) => {
            this.setState({
                selectedCategory: (history.location.state && history.location.state.category) ? history.location.state.category : 'sports',
            })
        }); 
    }

    handleSelect(key) {
        history.push("/Home",{'category':key})
    }

render () {
    return (
        <Tabs activeKey={this.state.selectedCategory} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="SportOrSocialSelector">
            <Tab eventKey={'sports} .../>
            <Tab eventKey={'social} .../>
        </Tabs>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could take would be to use query params with React router. And in your component change the tabs based on the query param. Since the url changed you should get the default behaviour your looking for.

Comment: I guess that could work, also thought about query parameter, but was holding back on using them because then somebody might copy the URL and might expect to arrive at the same open modal (which he would not).

Comment: Make a query param for the modal to be open or closed? And open it if its `true` pop the modal?

Comment: I use redux for opening the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project with almost exactly that situation. The difference, is that instead of it being in a modal, I have it in my header. Here is what I did:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="tabs tabs-fixed-width z-depth-1">
        <li className="tab">
          <Link id="books-tab" to={'/books'}>Books</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="tab">
          <Link id="stats-tab" to={'/stats'}>Stats</Link>
        </li>
        {Meteor.userId() &&
          <li className="tab">
            <Link id="user-tab" to={'/user'}>Account Settings</Link>
          </li>}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Header);
```

The `react-router-dom <Link>...` being the operative item that allows this to happen.

Then, when I click on the tab, each link goes to the specified url and keeps it in history so I can go back and get to the previous tab.

Comment: Not quite the same, check the answer I gave myself further below. The way I see it you would go to a new route, which I did not want to do. I did not want to change the URL.